# Как реализовать сохранение фотографий в Picasso?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bitmap, кэширование, picasso

В моем приложении рецептов есть функция сохранения рецепта для просмотра в оффлайн-режиме. Я реализовал сохранение текста в БД, но не знаю как быть с картинками. Пока что просто качаю `Bitmap` и сохраняю файл в память, запоминая его имя. Имя файла сохраняю в БД вместо ссылки.

Проблема очевидна - при получении `Bitmap` большой картинки выбрасывает `OutOfMemoryError`. Я прекрасно знаю про библиотеки и использую `Picasso` для показа картинок при подключенном интернете. Я также хорошо знаю, что она кэширует изображения. Также я знаю, что она качает их без `OutOfMemory`.

**НО**

Сохранение картинок реализовано в `AsyncTask`, а работать с `Picasso` в нем не получается.

Пока что думаю вместо загрузки картинок "руками" выкачивать `Bitmap` с помощью `Picasso`, но не понимаю как, нет логов, приложение просто вылетает.

Comment: Ну не создавай объект bitmap, а работай с потоком бит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы обратиться к `Picasso` выхожу в майн поток через `publishProgress` и в `onProgressUpdate()` передаю ссылку и имя файла. Также я использую `resize`. Тем самым картинки сохраняются не полностью, а под нужный размер. Работает отлично)

Comment: А зачем вообще тут `AsyncTask`? Ведь Picasso и так качает картинки асинхронно. Может проще будет совсем от него избавиться?

Comment: @eugeneek, как избавиться? У меня прогрессдиалог загрузки)

Comment: Показывать диалог перед вызовом начала загрузки и убирать в колбеке завершения. Без кода сложно сказать что-то больше, но использовать `AsyncTask` только для отображения диалога загрузки это однозначно оверхед)

Comment: @eugeneek, да у меня как только больше 15 классов, в которых активности, адаптеры и прочее - сразу везде оверхед :D А вообще, почему? Я показываю прогресс с процентами, мне таска нужна отдельная. Плюс наконец выйти из той кучи кода в отдельный класс, хух

Comment: @eugeneek, код не покажу! :s

Comment: Ну получается, что в асинк таске вы делаете что-то ещё, а не только скачиваете картинки при помощи Пикасо. Тогда вопросов нет.